# transfer ownership of spreadsheet file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to make code like bellow to transfer file ownership if the user make a copy of the file, but it not working

```
    function owner () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var name = namedRanges.getName()
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var lowner = file.getOwner();
  var owner = lowner.getEmail();

  if (owner =="my email"){
      }
    else {
  file.setOwner("my email");

  } 
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as well as the execution transcript or the textual error message as is suggested in [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean transfwr ownership? If the user copied your file he is already owner of this file. What is exactly your situation? And what are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setOwner() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(ss.getName());
  while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var owner = file.setOwner("my email");
  }
}
```